# How to configure Blue Card payment?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, sylius, payum

Testing a Sylius standard edition, I want to add Blue Card payment to payments methods, how ?

Comment: Depends of the bank... Banks often provides PHP packages. If the module you are looking for does not already exists in Sylius, you will have to make your own

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, how to create one.

Comment: Call your bank or the bank of the one your are developing for and ask for PHP payment module intégration. It could use **ATOS**, but could use another one. They will provide binaries and other stuff in one zip. From there, you can start developing.

Comment: How about Sylius configuration ?

Comment: It should be a simple Symfony2 bundle. I don't know more about Sylius, sorry...